# socket.io client 'on' only works after both clients 'emit'

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I'm opening up my page in two tabs. For some reason, the client 'on' only fires once both tabs have submitted a post.

```
// server
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('newPost', function (post) {
    io.emit('newPostReturn', post)
    console.log(post)
  })
})

// client (angular)
$rootScope.socket = io('http://172.28.28.201:3000');
$rootScope.socket.emit('newPost', post);
$rootScope.socket.on('newPost', function (post) {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.posts.push(post);
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

Changed to using https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io. Same problem. Also I notice that bizarrely after the 3rd emit each client re-runs 'on' another time. It's like the first time it triggers 'on' zero times, then every subsequent call it triggers it an additional time.

```
.factory('socket', function (socketFactory) {
  var ioSocket = io.connect('http://172.28.28.201:3000');

  socket = socketFactory({
    ioSocket: ioSocket
  });

  return socket;
});
```

UPDATE 2: I'm dumb!!

I had my 'on' handler INSIDE the submit post event. Moved it outside and, of course, everything works as expected. Everything makes perfect sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to create a service to create a service for handling the socket.io connection; look for [angular socket io](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) which is practically a service wrapper.

you'll have a less coupled implementation and it would be easier to handle the instance and the connections.

Comment: how do you think service can communicate between two tabs?\

Comment: Using that module now. Same problem. Every 'on' event seems to be firing a cumulative number of times. Updated my question

Comment: NEVERMIND! Silly mistake. Had my 'on' handler inside the submitPost event. Thanks!

Comment: @pankajparkar you'll get a separate instance for each tab since the nature of SPA's, so you'll get two connections, but it's better to abstract the functionality in a service, handle the client socket connection in a single place is a good start for looking at the problems.